# Why does this scheduler block Requests and how can it be prevented?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Our Kotlin(1.7.10)-based reactive Springboot(2.7.3) application uses a Scheduler like this to schedule Notifications for the frontend:

```
@Component
class NotificationScheduler(
  val transactionManager: ReactiveTransactionManager,
  val time: Time,
) {
  companion object {
    const val DELAY_BETWEEN_SCHEDULES = 5000L // milliseconds
  }

  val logger = logger()

  @Scheduled(
    fixedDelay = DELAY_BETWEEN_SCHEDULES
  )
  fun scheduler() {
    Mono.fromRunnable<Unit> {
      /* the transaction is required to keep row locks for the duration of the transaction
            to sync this scheduler to those of other instances */
      runBlocking {
        val tx = TransactionalOperator.create(transactionManager)
        tx.executeAndAwait {
          try {
            ...
          } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.error("NotificationCron rollback", e)
            it.isRollbackOnly
          }
          return@executeAndAwait
        }
      }
    }
      // this ensures that the above code runs on a different
      // thread from the selected thread pool
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
      .subscribe()
  }
}
```

The actual code inside the try-catch-block is quite computation intensive and includes a lot of Database-operations, both writing and reading. The intent is that each backend instance does this work on the side while still processing Requests from the frontend.
However, we found that the backend becomes unresponsive while it is doing this scheduling work.

We haven't managed to determine the cause of this. Is there a problem with the above code or is there a bottleneck elsewhere?

Comment: Apparently you are using row locks which can turn into page or table locks. That being said, depending on your schedule you might end up with multiple triggered jobs, which eventually will eat up the connections to the datbaase.

Comment: fixedDelay should only ever run once at a time, since the delay to start the next job begins after the previous one concludes.
So you think the Database is the most likely bottleneck?

Comment: I doubt that this is the only process that is running on your database. Also the determination if a row/page.table lock applies is made by the database and if you read a lot of data and lock the rows this might be upgraded to a higher level of locking, leading to issues with your other code. So it isn't really a database issue (that does what it is supposed to do) but rather a code issue. And it is a suggestion the only way to know for sure is to figure out what happens at the time things stop working.